# Aws CLI filters

Tags: amazon-web-services, filter, aws-cli

I would like to use aws cli filters.
Here I want to filter the minimum size of a scaling group, how do I do it?

```
 aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups  --query 'AutoScalingGroups[].[AutoScalingGroupName,MinSize=>0,MaxSize,DesiredCapacity,LaunchConfigurationName]
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for all autoscaling groups that have MinSize > 0, the CLI would look like:

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query 'AutoScalingGroups[?MinSize>`0`].[AutoScalingGroupName,MinSize,MaxSize,DesiredCapacity,LaunchConfigurationName]' --output text
```

If you are looking for all Autoscaling groups (irrespective of the capacity):

```
aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query 'AutoScalingGroups[].[AutoScalingGroupName,MinSize,MaxSize,DesiredCapacity,LaunchConfigurationName]' --output text
```